# Necesito que la primera opción del select sea siempre la misma

Tags: php, mysql

Chicos, tengo una pequeña consulta, resulta que tengo un formulario donde puedo modificar datos de un curso, y el usuario, a través de un select, ve que curso quiere modificar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle esta en que, cada vez que ingreso al sitio, siempre hay una opción pre seleccionada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que, cuando el usuario ingrese al link, la opción prefijada sea siempre "elija un curso a modificar",

Este es el código del select,

```html
 <select name="lista_cursos" id="lista_cursos" class="form-control" >
                    <option value=''>Elija un curso a modificar</option>
                    <?php 
                        $user_id=$_POST["user_id"];
                        $con = Conectarse();
                        $con->set_charset("utf8"); 
                        $query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 
                          cursos.id_curso, 
                          cursos.nombre_curso, 
                          jornadas_curso.id_jornadas,
                          DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS Fechas_Cursos
                      --    jornadas_curso.fechas_curso
                          FROM cursos
                          INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.fechas_curso >  NOW( ) 
                          AND jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
                          order by Fechas_Cursos DESC
                         -- group by cursos.id_curso");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_jornadas'].'">'.$valores['Fechas_Cursos'].' / '.$valores['nombre_curso'].'</option>';                       
                        } 
                     
                       ?>
                  </select>
```

Como puedo lograr esto?, Saludos y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Saludos para esto te sugiero realizar lo siguiente:

```js
//selecciono el select
miSelect = document.getElementById("cursos");
//defino selected la primera option
miSelect.selectedIndex = 0;
```

```html
<select id='cursos'>
<option>Seleccione un curso</option>
<option>Curso 1</option>
<option>Curso 2</option>
<option>Curso N</option>
</select>
```

si te fijas mediante JavaScript selecciono mi select por el ID y luego mediante este defino el option por su index en este caso "0" para que sea la primera opcion seleccionada.

Ahora con Jquery:

```js
$("#cursos option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='cursos'>
<option>Seleccione un curso</option>
<option>Curso 1</option>
<option>Curso 2</option>
<option>Curso N</option>
</select>
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el atributo selected en la opción que quieras tener por defecto puedes solucionar el problema:

```
<select name="lista_cursos" id="lista_cursos" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" >
                <option value='' selected>Elija un curso a modificar</option>
                <?php 
                    $user_id=$_POST["user_id"];
                    $con = Conectarse();
                    $con->set_charset("utf8"); 
                    $query =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 
                      cursos.id_curso, 
                      cursos.nombre_curso, 
                      jornadas_curso.id_jornadas,
                      DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS Fechas_Cursos
                  --    jornadas_curso.fechas_curso
                      FROM cursos
                      INNER JOIN jornadas_curso ON jornadas_curso.fechas_curso >  NOW( ) 
                      AND jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
                      order by Fechas_Cursos DESC
                     -- group by cursos.id_curso");
                    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                      echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_jornadas'].'">'.$valores['Fechas_Cursos'].' / '.$valores['nombre_curso'].'</option>';                       
                    } 

                   ?>
              </select>
```

Comment: de hecho lo habia agregado como dijiste, pero aún persiste el problema, saludos

Comment: Mmmm intenta agregar autocomplete="off" Al select en el caso de que se encuentre en un form, actualizaré el código de todas formas.

Comment: Le agregue el autocomplete y aun nada, toma la primera fila de la query y la muestra apenas uno carga el link

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este ejemplo aver si te funciona

```html
<select name="lista_cursos" id="lista_cursos" required title="Seleccionar tipo de curso" class="form-control" required>
<option value="0">Elija un curso a modificar</option>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, hice la prueba pero sin resultado, saludos

Comment: Te mostro algun error? no se te ejecuto el programa? siguio igual? Te hizo algun cambio?

Comment: siguió igual, no queda como primera opción "Elija un curso a modificar"

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria asi:

```html
<select id='cursos'>
<option disabled selected>Seleccione un curso</option>
<option>Curso 1</option>
<option>Curso 2</option>
<option>Curso N</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Estupendo. ¿Puedes expandir tu respuesta para hablar de otras cosas poco conocidas de `option`?